# @ngrx/store - The store does not return the data in async/away manner

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have a problem while getting the value from the store. The operation hangs. I try to get the data in the following way:

```
async onInit(params: Params) { 
  // it hangs on the line bellow
  var userToken = await this.store.select(fromRoot.getUserToken).toPromise();  
  console.log(userToken);
}
```

then I execute the following async function:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.onInit(params).then(() => console.log('promise executed'));
});
```

The user token is never returned.

If I subscribe to the store then it works fine.

```
this.store.select(fromRoot.getUserToken).subscribe(ut => {
  console.log(ut);
});
```

Comment: You really want to loose the power of observable and use a promise only to have async/await in your app ?! You could also just use the async pipe in your view ...

Comment: @Maxime Imagine a sitation when you want to read the latest values from your observables and execute a remote method only once.

Comment: If you want to get only one value, simply use the `first` operator which'll end the stream after a value is emitted ;)

Comment: I would like a solution to this as well. I need to get the user object in a guard to see if the user's authenticated or redirect. I don't need to use the object in a view, I need toPromise() to work with async/await so I can work with the object without building pyramids. I dislike how Observables brought back callback hell without asking anyone, without solutions and now even messing up Promises.

Comment: could you make it work?

Answer (score 6):

I recently had this problem as well. As @maxime1992 indicates you need an operator to end the observable.

```js
    async onInit(params: Params) { 
        // it hangs on the line bellow
        const userToken = await this.store.select(fromRoot.getUserToken).pipe(take(1)).toPromise();  
        console.log(userToken);                                      // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     
    }
```

Update for rxjs 7+, now we use firstValueFrom or lastValueFrom:

```js
    async onInit(params: Params) { 
        // it hangs on the line bellow
        const userToken = await firstValueFrom(this.store.select(fromRoot.getUserToken).pipe(take(1)));  
        console.log(userToken); // ^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                      ^
    }
```